# Want to see which numbers in Column A are not in Column B

Tags: microsoft-excel

I would like to see which numbers in Column A are not in Column B, with "Yes" or "No" displayed in Column C. I am trying to find a text with 10 numeric digits.

More specifically, I want to know which digits are in column A that are not in Column B. These are ISBNs of books that often begin with 0. Is there a format that would work better? As indicated, the results should be in Column C.

*Example Data*

[image: Example Data Screenshot]

Comment: Please mock up some test data with expected output. [edit] your post to include that data in text format, so we can copy paste.  Also show what you have tried to accomplish this goal explaining where it is at fault

Comment: `COUNTIF` can be useful.

Comment: You can use COUNTIF and Conditional Formatting.

Answer (score 3):

In **C1** enter:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(B:B,A1)>0,"YES","NO")
```

and copy downward.  For example:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

- Enter this Formula in `C2` and Fill it down.

`IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A1,$B$1:$B$9,1,FALSE)),"Not in B","Yes")`

*Adjust Cell references in the Formula as needed.*

Comment: @fixer1234, First Part is just to handle blank cells, yes is true that it can be omitted, my Formula returns Yes for Values in Both A & B and No for the Value in A but not in B.

Comment: @fixer1234, actually OP wants Yes/No otherwise this may also work,, `=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A1,$B$1:$B$9,1,FALSE)),"Not in B","Yes")`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91737/discussion-between-rajesh-s-and-fixer1234).

Comment: In the future would be good to take screenshots to include column and row header so it would be clear to which cells your formula refers to.